# AngularJs. Cycle in $scope.$watch

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I can't understand whats wrong. I need create array of hours and minutes and show him.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="test">
    <div ng-controller="timeCtrl" ng-init="opentime='9';closetime='24'">
        <div ng-repeat="time in times">
            <a href="#">{{time}}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('test', []);

app.controller('timeCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.$watch('opentime', function () {

        $scope.times = [];    

        for (var hours = $scope.opentime; hours < $scope.closetime; hours++) {

        console.log(hours);

            for (var minutes = 0; minutes < 4; minutes++) {

                var linkMinutes = minutes * 15;

                if (linkMinutes === 0) {
                    linkMinutes = "00";
                }

            console.log(linkMinutes);

            $scope.times.push(hours + ':' + linkMinutes);

            }
        }


    });


}])
```

Why console.log is empty, but vars opentime and closetime with value?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Zoomer/mj8zv2qL/

Answer (score 0):

that because your scope variable `opentime` never been changed to fire watcher

I'v updated the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/mj8zv2qL/8/) and simulated the variable change

Comment: Thanks, but I'm confused. Without $watch I can't get the values from the ng-init?

Comment: because ng-init works before your directive registers watchers

Answer (score 0):

scope.$watch will execute only when `opentime` change value please see more here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

and that demo http://jsfiddle.net/oprhy6te/[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/oprhy6te/)

**CTRL:**

```
app.controller('timeCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.$watch('opentime', function () {

        $scope.updateTimes();

    });


    $scope.updateTimes = function () {
        $scope.times = [];

        for (var hours = $scope.opentime; hours < $scope.closetime; hours++) {

            console.log(hours);

            for (var minutes = 0; minutes < 4; minutes++) {

                var linkMinutes = minutes * 15;

                if (linkMinutes === 0) {
                    linkMinutes = "00";
                }

                console.log(linkMinutes);

                $scope.times.push(hours + ':' + linkMinutes);

            }
        }
    }

    function activate() {
        $scope.opentime = 9;
        $scope.closetime = 13;
        $scope.updateTimes();

    }

      activate();

}])
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="test">
    <div ng-controller="timeCtrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="opentime" />
        <div ng-repeat="time in times"> <a href="#">{{time}}</a> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I understood everything. Like the fact that I can't use ng-init. To get the values I can only from a template, which is not Angular-way.

Comment: @user3843670 you're welcome just there is a link to proper demo http://jsfiddle.net/oprhy6te/